# Javascript problem with switch statement that find not case: "none"

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, switch-statement, output

My code has to see if there is a ball in a mapPoint and then changing the color of the pixels where the ball is by the color of the ball.
Here is my code:

```
function UpdateColorInMapPoints(mapPointIndexs)
{
    mapPointIndexs.forEach(mapPointIndex => {
        var mapPointData=ballsMap[mapPointIndex]
        var ballsAtTheMapPoint=ballsMap[mapPointIndex].balls;
        var temperature;
        if(ballsAtTheMapPoint.length>0)
        {
            temperature=balls[ballsAtTheMapPoint[ballsAtTheMapPoint.length-1]].temperature;
        }else
        {
            temperature="none1";
        }
        var column,line=0;
        while(line<scale)
        {
            column=0;
            while(column<scale)
            {
                putTemperatureColorAt(temperature,(mapPointData.horizontalPosition*scale+column)*4+(mapPointData.verticalPosition*scale+line)*4*imgWidth*scale);
                column++;
            }
            line++;
        }
    });
    canvasContext.putImageData(ImgData,0,0);
}

function putTemperatureColorAt(temperature,index)
{
    switch(Math.round(temperature))
    {
        case -5:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case -4:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=50;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=200;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case -3:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=100;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=150;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case -2:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=150;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=100;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case -1:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=200;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=50;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case 0:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case 1:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=200;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case 2:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=150;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case 3:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=100;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case 4:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=50;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case 5:
        ImgData.data[index+0]=255;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        case "none1":
        ImgData.data[index+0]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+1]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+2]=0;
        ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Impossible to find color:"+temperature);
    }
}
```

when i run the code, console say : "Impossible to find color: none1"
this means that temperature="none1" but if temperature="none1" the outpout of switch shouldn't be default cause there is case "none1":

```
       case "none1":
            ImgData.data[index+0]=0;
            ImgData.data[index+1]=0;
            ImgData.data[index+2]=0;
            ImgData.data[index+3]=255;
                break;
```

I very don't understand wath's wrong, i hope my english wasn't too bad.

Comment: Won't `Math.round('none1')` resolve as `NaN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your switch to the following:

```js
switch (isFinite(temperature) ? Math.round(temperature) : temperature) {
  // ...
}
```

You want to avoid rounding on a non-finite value aka an invalid `Number`.

---

### Example

```js
const process = (temperature) => {
  switch (isFinite(temperature) ? Math.round(temperature) : temperature) {
    case 0: return 'Zero';
    case 1: return 'One';
    case 'none1': return 'None';
    default: throw new Error(`Unknown temperature: ${temperature}`);
  }
};

console.log(process(0.2));       // Zero
console.log(process(0.8));       // One
console.log(process('none1'));   // None
console.log(process(undefined)); // throw Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your switch statement.

```js
console.log(Math.round("none1"))
```